# return ArrayList<String> with specific record from SQLiteDataBase

Tags: android

I want to get values but the function always returns null. Even though I debug and there is value inside variable rv.
This is my method:

```
public ArrayList<String> getList(int id) {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<String>();
        open();
        Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from reviews where IDRE="+id, null);
        if(c.moveToFirst() || c.getColumnCount()==1) {
                rv.add(String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("IDRE"))));
                rv.add(String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID_FK"))));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DATE")));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TYPE")));
                rv.add(String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("COST"))));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SERVICE")));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ATMOSPHERE")));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("OVERALL")));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COMMENT")));
        }
        c.close();
        close();
        return rv;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is `(c.moveToFirst() || c.getColumnCount()==1) ` ever true? If not, that would explain why `rv` never contains a value.

Comment: what is open and close methods ?

Comment: database.open() and database.close()

Comment: can you post code for that ?

Comment: You're probably getting an exception thrown.  Put a log entry inside the `catch` block, and see if it gets logged.

Comment: `function always returns null`. From your code snippet only thing which return `NUL` is **catch block** so you have some exception on your code, post exception stacktrace with your code.

Comment: public void open() throws SQLException {
  db = dbhelper.getWritableDatabase();
 }

Comment: and what about close method ?

Comment: `c.getColumnCount()==1` Are you sure that is correct?  You then proceed to access 9 columns.

Comment: close method is db.close();

Answer (score 0):

Some logging would help determine if you're throwing an error and ending up in that catch block, as @Daniel Nugent is saying.

But I think the issue is with your `if` expression. `c.moveToFirst` is going to move your `cursor` to the first row of your data source, and then return `true` unless that data source is empty, so the only time that `if` block does not occur is when your data source is empty. The only way `c.getColumnCount()==1` is having any effect on the evaluation of your expression is if you have a table with only one column and no rows. Let us know what you're trying to achieve with that, and add some logging, and we'll be better able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

**I have edited your code ...and given two example , you can refer any one...**

```
public ArrayList<String> getList(int id) {
        try {
            ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<String>();

            open();

            Cursor c = db.rawQuery("select * from reviews where IDRE="+id, null);
            if(c==null)
                return null;
            c.moveToFirst();
                    rv.add(String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("IDRE"))));
                    rv.add(String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID_FK"))));
                    rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DATE")));
                    rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TYPE")));
                    rv.add(String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("COST"))));
                    rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SERVICE")));
                    rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ATMOSPHERE")));
                    rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("OVERALL")));
                    rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COMMENT")));

            c.close();
            close();
            return rv;
        }catch(Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }
```

**Second way:**

```
public ArrayList<String> getList(int id) {
    try {
        ArrayList<String> rv = new ArrayList<String>();

        open();
        String[] columns=new String[]{"IDRE","ID_FK","DATE","TYPE","COST","SERVICE","ATMOSPHERE","OVERALL","COMMENT"};
        Cursor c=sql_db.query("reviews", columns, "IDRE"+"=?", new String[] {String.valueOf(id)}, null, null, null);


        if(c==null)
            return null;
        c.moveToFirst();
                rv.add(String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("IDRE"))));
                rv.add(String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("ID_FK"))));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("DATE")));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("TYPE")));
                rv.add(String.valueOf(c.getInt(c.getColumnIndex("COST"))));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("SERVICE")));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("ATMOSPHERE")));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("OVERALL")));
                rv.add(c.getString(c.getColumnIndex("COMMENT")));

        c.close();
        close();
        return rv;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks guy, I will try them, but I have some questions, If I ignore this "c.getColumnCount()==1". Does the cursor know ID exists

Comment: Yeah!...Your question is appreciated... don't ignore this method for verification... Cursor contains all these information based on your initialized method...as we have used in above example...

Comment: or you can use cursor.getCount() method  to validate weather cursor contains data or not...even cursor contains data then the count would return the number of records..else return 0 only (no data available into cursor) ....Happy to Spread the knowledge....I hope it would help you ..